# Javascript to wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a HTML/CSS form which requires an external Javascript. I have the HTML on my required page with linking code to the javascript. I have a wordpress website and I just put the folder with the javascript in Public_HTML. Is this correct, it is not working for some reason?
Code in HTML:

```
    <script src="csgoboost/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="csgoboost/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="csgoboost/js/boosting.js"></script>
```

Thank (I am a bit of a beginner)

Comment: Might be the path issue. see if it included properly

Comment: you need to learn first template hierarchy of wordpress before implementing. [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and [directory structure](https://digwp.com/2012/05/complete-list-wordpress-files/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom JavaScript, CSS and HTML to WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166206/adding-custom-javascript-css-and-html-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using wordpress then put the js folder in themes folder like

`public_html/wp-content/themes/yourThemeName/js-folder`

and then call the

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js-folder/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, I've done shat your told me to but it seems like it still doesn't work.. =(

Comment: I know, I have put the JS folder in there

Comment: in the header.php file or footer.php file you call this function

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js-folder/file.js"></script>

Comment: Oh I put it in the page with my HTML form. Do I also put it in the header?

Comment: Put in header or footer.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I put it in the footer, and the body. And I put the JS Folder in the theme folder...